# why can't i receive information from mysql1 select query (in Dart)?

Tags: mysql, dart

I'm using mysql1 in Dart to connect with my MySQL databases.
It does very well with insert query but it comes to be messy with the select one. I can't get the right results from my database (in fact it returns nothing).
Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Open a connection (students_info should already exist)
  final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      user: 'root',
      db: 'students_info',
      password: 'secret'));

  // This is ok, it adds to my databases
  
  // var res = await conn.query(
  //   '''
  //     INSERT INTO students_info.students VALUES (14, 'alsdjflajdf', 'adsgaf', 'tqwe', '3.9');
  //   '''
  // );
  // print(res);

  var results = await conn.query(
      'select * from students;'
  );


  // 0 here, idk why?
  print(results.length);
  // Finally, close the connection
  await conn.close();
}
```

Can you guys explain me why? The connection is true (I've tested with the insert one and the select query returns everything I need if I run it in MySql Workbench).

Comment: Could you try remove the semicolon from your query? So `select * from students` instead of `select * from students;`.